# MySQL Database limit if creates different DB for each ZipCode

Tags: mysql, sqlperformance

I am working on web application which uses MySQL and reached 100,000 records for one of biggest transaction table. It contains data for multiple store chain across country.

Is it good idea to have different DB for each ZipCode and have those store under that ZipCode based DB to reduce the performance impact in future due to huge amount of data?

Wherever business chain will introduce store at new ZipCode, script will create new DB to onboard it.

There will be single DB for initial store authentication / login, after authentication REST API will redirect request to DB for that ZipCode.

What is the MySQL database limit for number of DB creation?
Is architectural idea I am proposing seems OK?

Comment: Assuming your database needs to cover the continental US, you could consider creating a geographic logical partition on your data, based on the ZIP code/location.  Read about partitioning for more information.

Comment: "Is it good idea to have different DB for each ZipCode and have those store under that ZipCode based DB to reduce the performance impact in future due to huge amount of data?" No bad idea besides MySQL is able to handle millions or even billions of records in one table just fine when indexes are used.. Like @TimBiegeleisen said you might consider partitioning but partitioning is not always a silver bullet for gaining performance..

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen only single master data table will have ZipCode not other 30+ transaction tables which will contains huge number of records. I am not sure how partitioning will work here. Indexing will help here to some extent.